# find the size of an array as you read the file

Tags: java

So I have a file which has integer values. I do not want to use the arraylist class in any way shape or form. I only want to go through the file once. How can I determine the size of my array while storing values at the same time?

Comment: The size of what array? Why don't you want to use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to do so, but there must be some way I can store the integers and go through the file once and then somehow fine the size of the array.

Comment: by my array I mean an array that stores the integer values in the file. I can't, do that, however, because I don't know  the size of my array.

Comment: You'd implement a counter and increment it every time you loaded an element into whatever data structure you end up using. This said, your problem is an ideal candidate for ArrayList, so I'm thinking this is some sort of homework. Are you allowed to use counters?

Comment: Every time you get to the end of the array, make a new array that's twice as big. (That's how `ArrayList` does it)

Comment: @immibis: should that be an answer perhaps?

Comment: I think I found a way that might work. I was thinking of storing everything in one string separated by commas, and then split the string and store each element in the array. I can count the size of the array using the method MarsAtomic mentioned. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array that is big, large enough to fit the maximum possible number of items (how much is dependent on your current job/work/homework specification), and fill it partially with all the data you read in. Keep count of how many items are entered so you don't go over when using the array.